# Is there good way to minify ES2016 javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, minify

I'm using ES2016 without babel. When I minify my source code after babel, I often use `uglify-js` package on npm.

It fairly works well for ES5 codes. But it not work with ES2016 code.

Error messsage `SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (MyClassName)` would generated by executing uglify-js with ES2016 code.

Is there any good way to minify ES2016 code as keeping it ES2016?

Comment: For ES2016 I use [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), but it converts ES2016 code to ES5. I think there is no complete ES2016 minifier.

Comment: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448 For existing solutions (no mangling or fancy stuff) see this http://prettydiff.com/

Comment: https://github.com/babel/babili was just released.

Comment: The question is off-topic so it will be closed anyway...

Comment: Babili looks promising but they have a breaking bug for any array destructure inside of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jscompress.com/ does the job if you are looking for a web solution.
For an offline solution you can use https://github.com/babel/babili as mentioned before.